Existence of certain function satisfying certain conditions
I want to show that there does not exist $f ∈ C([0, 1], R)$ satisfying the following two conditions:
(i) $\int_{0}^{1} 
f(x) dx = 1$; 
(ii) $\lim_{n\to\infty}
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^n dx = 0.$
Suppose there exist such function and assume $1-f(x)\geq 0\forall x\in [0,1],$
then we have $\int_{0}^{1} 
(1-f(x) )dx=0 $, which gives $1-f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1\forall x\in [0,1],$
which doesn't satisfy (ii).
Now let $f(c)>1$ then for some $c\in(0,1)$ and $\delta>0$, we have
$\lim_{n\to\infty}
\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}f(x)^{2n} dx>2\delta>0$, is this correct?
Any alternative hints and proofs will be appreciated.

Your argument is basically a correct outline of a proof. If this is for a class you need to clarify some points. For example, you need to explain exactly how and where you use $f$ is continuous.

continuity is used where i said function is $>1$ in nbd of $c$ and $1-f(x)\geq0$.  your alternative proofs will also be helpful.

Alternative proof: (By Hölder's inequality/ Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) we have $1=\int_0^{1} f(x)dx\leq (\int_0^{1} f(x)^{2n})^{1/2n}<1$ if $n$ is sufficiently large.
Continuity of $f$ is not needed!

continuity not needed but, then $f\in L^1[0,1]$?

Yes, any measurable $f$ for which $\int f^{2n}$  exists would do.

I am in favor of explicit $ \varepsilon-\delta $ proofs, whenever possible. If that is not your favorite type of proof, there are also other options, of course.
There are two cases: $f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$ and $f(x)>1$ for some $x$.
$\mathbf{First \, case}$:
If $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, then $\int_0^1 f^n=\int_0^1 1 = 1$ for all $n$, so (ii) fails.
If $f(x)\leq 1 $ for all $x$ and $f(c)<1$ for some $c\in(0,1)$. Let $\varepsilon = \tfrac{1-f(c)}{2}.$  By continuity there is a $\delta>0$ such that  $f(x) < f(c)+\varepsilon=\tfrac{1+f(c)}{2}$ for all $x\in (c-\delta, c+\delta)\subseteq (0,1).$ Hence $\int_0^1 f \leq \int_0^{c-\delta} 1 + \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} \tfrac{1+f(c)}{2} + \int_{c+\delta}^1 1 = 1-\delta(1-f(c)) < 1$ so (i) fails.
$\mathbf{Second \, case}$:
If $f(c)>1$ for some $c\in(0,1).$ Let $\varepsilon=f(c)-1$. By continuity there is a $\delta>0$ such that  $f(x) > f(c)-\varepsilon=1$ for all $x\in (c-\delta, c+\delta)\subseteq (0,1).$ Hence $\int_0^1 f^{2n}\geq \int_0^{c-\delta} 0 + \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} 1 + \int_{c+\delta}^1 0 = 2\delta $ so (ii) fails.
A very careful proof would explain why we can assume $c\neq 0,1$ and $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\subseteq(0,1).$

When I wrote the line you mentioned at the end, I still don't know why I wrote that ,it is like my instinct not allowing $c=0,1$.

If $c$ is $0$ or $1$ a simple continuity argument shows $c'\neq 0,1$ exists. So not really a problem.

What is $c'$ here

If in case 2 we started with $f(0)>1$, then $c'>0$ would be close to $0$ with $f(c')>1.$ The 'prime' was just to notationally make it different from $c$.
